# Does Android Early Resume makes sense?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, android-source

I been going through Linux Power management, I find android implementation for "Early Resume", how can this work? I find early suspend makes sense while Android Stack gets finished with Suspend related jobs and System suspending device. How does early resume work when System is not resumed?

Comment: Can you share a path into the Android source or documentation for this?

Comment: Some links for this: [Link-1](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/development/pdk/docs/power_management.html)  [Link-2](http://www.blogjava.net/anymobile/articles/328591.html) though these websites don't represent Google, Is that these API's are depreciated and "android_register_late_resume" is implemented?